# Some confusing of the understanding of groups in python regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I'm getting confused groups of Regex which from a  book:《Automate the Boring Stuff with Python: Practical Programming for Total Beginners 》。The Regex as follow:

```
#! python3
# phoneAndEmail.py - Finds phone numbers and email addresses on the clipboard
# The data of paste from: https://www.nostarch.com/contactus.html
import pyperclip, re

phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''(
     (\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?              # area code
     (\s|-|\.)?                      # separator
     (\d{3})                         # first 3 digits
     (\s|-|\.)                       # separator  
     (\d{4})                         # last 4 digits
     (\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,,5}))? # extension
     )''', re.VERBOSE )

# TODO: Create email regex.

emailRegex = re.compile(r'''(
     [a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+               # username
      @                              # @ symbol
     [a-zA-Z0-9.-]+                  # domian name
     (\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})               # dot-something
     )''', re.VERBOSE)
# TODO: Find matches in clipboard text.

text = str(pyperclip.paste())
matches = []
for groups in phoneRegex.findall(text):
    **phoneNum = '-'.join ([groups[1], groups[3], groups[5]])
    if groups[8]!= '':
      phoneNum += ' x' + groups[8]**
    matches.append(phoneNum)
print(groups[0])
for groups in emailRegex.findall(text):
    matches.append(groups[0])

# TODO: Copy results to the clipboard.

if len(matches) > 0:
    pyperclip.copy('\n'.join(matches))
    print('Copied to clipboard:')
    print('\n'.join(matches))
else:
    print('No phone number or email addresses found.')
```

I am confused about **groups[1](http://http//www.nostarch.com/contactus.html)/groups[2]……/groups[8]**. And how many groups in the phoneRegex. And what is the difference between **groups()** and **groups[]**.

The data of paste from: [https://www.nostarch.com/contactus.html]

Comment: You should read the tutorial at www.regular-expression.info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regexes can have *groups*. They are denoted by `()`. Groups can be used to extract a part of the match which might be useful.

In the phone number regex for example, there are 9 groups:

```
Group  Subpattern
1      ((\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?(\s|-|\.) (\d{3}) (\s|-|\.)(\d{4})(\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,,5}))?)
2      (\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?
3      (\s|-|\.)
4      (\d{3})
5      (\s|-|\.)
6      (\d{4})
7      (\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,,5}))?
8      (ext|x|ext.)
9      (\d{2,,5})
```

Note how each group is enclosed in `()`s.

The `groups[x]` is just referring to the string matched by a particular group. `groups[0]` means the string matched by group 1, `groups[1]` means the string matched by group 2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In a regex, parenthesis `()` create what is called a **capturing group**. Each group is assigned a number, starting with 1.

For example:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: m = re.match('([0-9]+)([a-z]+)', '123xyz')

In [3]: m.group(1)
Out[3]: '123'

In [4]: m.group(2)
Out[4]: 'xyz'
```

Here, `([0-9]+)` is the first capturing group, and `([a-z]+)` is the second capturing group. When you apply the regex, the first capturing group ends up "capturing" the string `123` (since that's the part it matches), and the second part captures `xyz`.

With `findall`, it searches the string for all places where the regex matches, and for each match, it returns the list of captured groups as a tuple. I'd encourage you to play with it a bit in `ipython` to understand how it works. Also check the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.findall